# Implementing Event Grid in LogicApps for Sharepoint

Tags: events, triggers, azure-logic-apps

I have a process in LogicApps for ingesting a data from ADLS to Sharepoint storage, my question is how can I use event based trigger for process execution, also is there a way to use event based trigger from Sharepoint to LogicApps :)
[image]

Comment: Can you please add what you have tried and where you are facing the errors or blockers?

Comment: I have a 2way processing read files from sharepoint to adls storage and from storage to Sharepoint, i want if something changes in storage to be activated event trigger and to be processed back to Sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one of the ways that you can achieve your requirement. In this case, you can use `When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)` trigger to trigger the flow if there is any change that happened in storage. Then I'm getting the details and its content using `Get blob content (V2)` and finally I'm updating the file in SharePoint using `Update file`.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

***RESULTS IN LOGIC APP***

[image]

***RESULTS IN SHAREPOINT***

[image]

The same goes the other way i.e.. from SharePoint to Azure Blob Storage.

[image]

**NOTE:** Make sure you are mentioning the locations and the name of the blob right.